# How do I integrate Intel IPP with ros

Tags: ros, intel

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have downloaded Intel IPP and installed it.  I have written much code in the past with IPP and would like to use it with ROS.  Does anybody know how to integrate it into CMakeLists.txt and package.xml to make it work with ROS?  I am kind of new to Linux and ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264098/how-do-i-integrate-intel-ipp-with-ros/) by [Bob H](https://answers.ros.org/users/30141/bob-h/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS uses Catkin to build packages, which is basically CMake.

I suggest you try and find out how CMake could be convinced to 'use' IPP, I would expect that to work with Catkin as well.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0